how to improve 3d scans ? (workflow)
I just got a 3D scanner, and I am a bit wondering about the first scan results.
.. way to much face...
Sure I could do a retopo, it be a lot of work but I'll manage.
Or I could do a remesh using the sculpting tools
Or I could do a undevide or remesh modifier.
Though that's not what I really want...
I would rather have some kind of mesh cleanup as we have remove by distance in Blender.
Or maybe add to it that if the edge angles are below a certain threshold collapse face.
Because I noticed sometimes a lot of minuscule verticles are not really meaningful to the structure.
Also due to the technique of scanning, a certain kind of surface hill/valley noise (moire?) seems to be present in 3d scans, it's barely noticeable but I see it.
Sure we could smooth verticles, and I have bought a volume smoothing addon.
And there is laplacian smooth as well.
I just am wondered how others clean up their scans.
My goal is to 3d print some of the stone sculptures I made.
So I wonder what the best cleaning "recipes" are for 3d scans in Blender community?.
I'm no stranger to Blender, though I'm not so good in geometry nodes if there are solutions in that area I be keen to know too.

A detail of the eye as a sample of 'face' artefacts that I would like to clean.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

When you say you want something like collapsing when the edge angle is below a certain threshold... have you tried X > Limited Dissolve in Edit Mode? There you can specify angles in the tool options below which edges should be dissolved.

https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

Thanks forgot about that one, however it creates very odd surfaces
